# How to clean out base oil entirely

Tags: automotive-engineering

I've got a fluid line filled with base oil (Lubricant Oil). Would running detergent through it clean the line? I was thinking of running normal detergent water through it.

I'd like to use the same machine with food stuff afterwards so I'd like to be thorough. I thought maybe use some solvent first, but the fluid line I've got is PVC, PEX, rubber and SS, so didn't know what else I would lose along the way.

Comment: It would. Concentrated stuff (like dish soap) + hot water works well.

Comment: ok, because I'd like to use the same machine with food stuff afterwards so I'd like to be thorough. I thought maybe use some solvent first, but the fluid line I've got is PVC, PEX, rubber and SS, so didn't know what else I would lose along the way.

Comment: @jsotola edited

Comment: I suggest if your lube oil was not food grade that you should familiarize yourself with standards of cleanliness for food manufacture.  After you clean oil with detergent you will have to clean the detergent from the line.

Comment: @TigerGuy I am not selling this thing, its my own personal use, so standards can be more realistic and less rigid. Cleaning detergent is easy and I've done it before, and even if there are detergent traces left then it won't kill me.